# What version of MSOLAP provider am i using?

Tags: ssas, sql-server-2019, olap, oledb

We've just upgraded a Server from SQL Server 2016 to 2019.

We have linked servers connecting to an OLAP cube.

When I look under providers for MSOLAP the label of the dialog box shows:

> Microsoft OLE DB Provider for Analysis Services 14.0

If I look at a linked server The drop down for provider also says:

> Microsoft OLE DB Provider for Analysis Services 14.0

When I look in: C:\Program Files\Microsoft Analysis Services\AS OLEDB I have 2 folders:

- 130
- 140

If I look under 130 at the properties for MSOLAP130.dll it says it is version 13.0.5622.0

If I look under 140 at the properties for MSOLAP.dll it says it is version 15.1.65.24

Which DLL Is my linked server using? 13.xx or 15.xx?

Answer (score 1):

You can use SysInternals Process Explorer to find which DLL is in use.  Find > Handle or DLL. Type MSOLAP in the search field then connect to your DB and hit search in Process Explorer. The result will be the path to the MSOLAP DLL in use.

Answer (score 0):

For SQL Server 2019 it is Folder 140

Comment: Sorry for such a short answer. I have no Microsoft docs link for this. I just know this from experience. This is the default path in the Sql Server ISO installation routine. I have recently done a lot of SQL Server 2019 installations for our customers because many are upgrading know.